# White space at bottom in Windows Phone 8 phone gap app

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I have develop phone gap application on Android & Windows Phone. But for Windows Phone, it shows white space at bottom. From net, I get this answer: add this code to CSS

```
 @media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
    @-ms-viewport {
      width: 320px;
      user-zoom: fixed;
      max-zoom: 1;
      min-zoom: 1;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
      @-ms-viewport {
        width: 480px;
        user-zoom: fixed;
        max-zoom: 1;
        min-zoom: 1;
      }
    }
```

I add this code but doesn't show any effect. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include this in Index.html,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi, user-scalable=0" />
```

Include this in CSS:

```
@viewport
{
width:320px;
}

@-ms-viewport {
width:320px;
zoom-user:fixed;
max-zoom:1;
min-zoom:1;
}
```

and include also this,

```
body, html { 
  -ms-overflow-style: none !important; 
}
```

This will solve the issue for now, it worked for me in the same situation..!!
:-)

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please don't post the exact same answer to multiple questions -- once you have 50 reputation, you'll be able to flag questions for closure if they are exactly the same. Thanks!

Comment: What should i do ? wait for my reputation to become 50 ? i just wanna help the people who searched for this solution. i think you better link all that questions or remove the duplicate ones or mark all questions as duplice since all questions are of same nature..!!

Comment: I just now flagged all these questions as duplicates of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20476010/phonegap-windows-phone-8-viewport-meta-scaling-issue, since that one seems to have the nicest looking question.