# How to fit website on Windows Phone viewport

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, viewport, web-deployment

I've got website and on Android all works good but on iOS and WP, first two divs are one by one but they should display in one row.

Ealier I was using initial-scale but it only works on webkit so I abandoned that.

For now I'm really confused why and how to force my website to working with viewport 320.
site: http://piaskownica.lokalnamanufaktura.pl/metod/index480.html

Comment: You can use media queries

Comment: You should search a little this is a duplicate!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Phonegap + Windows Phone 8 : viewport meta & scaling issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20476010/phonegap-windows-phone-8-viewport-meta-scaling-issue)

Answer (score 0):

1)win phone algorithms is same with IE +10. so you should use some enhacment code for IE in your html page.
2) did you determine multi-screen pages via css ([LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847755/css-media-queries-for-screen-sizes))?

Comment: 1) When I added hack for IE +10 to use initial-scale nothing changed. 
2) Yes i'm using media queries. On desktop works well

Comment: @AdrianRatajczak can i see your page? (at least in jsfield.net)

Comment: itis added at top but catch http://piaskownica.lokalnamanufaktura.pl/metod/index480.html

Comment: @AdrianRatajczak i saw more CSS that controlling your screen size. instead you should use fullPageJS (http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/apple.html)

Comment: Why I should use FullPage.js? I don't see any advantages of that

Comment: resizing without problem, i tested it in 25 device (CS5 device central).

Comment: my website? if yes, its pretty strange

Comment: @AdrianRatajczak no, fullPagejs, but i saw no problem in 4 browsers here (IE, opera, Chrome,Firefox) with your site, also i resized the all browser to set as a mobile device then your site changed as a mobile page. and no 320px in start. started normally.can i know what is your mobile page tester?

Comment: I'm testing my webpage with lumia 920. I don't know any others way to test it.